# Programmatically check whether a linux kernel module exists or not at runtime

Tags: c, kernel-module, system-calls

I am writing a C daemon, which depends on the existence of two kernel modules in order to do its job. The program does not directly use these (or any other) modules. It only needs them to exist.
Therefore, I would like to programmatically check whether these modules are already loaded or not, in order to warn the user at runtime.

Before I start to do things like parsing `/proc/modules` or `lsmod` output, does a utility function already exist somewhere?
Something like `is_module_loaded(const char* name)`;

I am pretty sure this has been asked before.
However, I think I am missing the correct terms to search for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `popen` and `lsmod | grep` trick:

```
  FILE *fd = popen("lsmod | grep module_name", "r");

  char buf[16];
  if (fread (buf, 1, sizeof (buf), fd) > 0) // if there is some result the module must be loaded
    printf ("module is loaded\n");
  else
    printf ("module is not loaded\n");
```

Comment: Looks very dirty but it works and I have never thought about such simple solution. Cheers

Comment: Given that lsmod opens "/proc/modules", and that grep involves another process and additional file opens for the pipe, would it be more efficient to use "grep module_name /proc/modules"  and check whether there is any output from that instead? This would also work even if lsmod wasn't available.

Comment: A better grep would be '^module_name ' with a space after the name.

Answer (score 18):

There is no such function.  In fact, the source code of lsmod (`lsmod.c`) has the following line in it which should lead you to your solution:

```
file = fopen("/proc/modules", "r");
```

There is also a deprecated [`query_module`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/query_module) but it appears to only exist in kernel headers these days.

Comment: My question was ambiguous enough to both ask for the existence of such function and how to code the functionality. Therefore, I am going to upvote your answer and accept @tozka answer, because it works for me. Thanks for the explanations!

Comment: I used this solution. I hope the text format stays put for many years. I'm checking for "Live" in field 5: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/s2-proc-modules